# Python: How would I compare two strings using a function with only one of the strings as an argument?

Tags: python, string, comparison

I've created a class, and I am unsure how to approach the following problem. Is it possible to create a function that will be able to do what is in the example? (For practical uses, I would be comparing dates and returning true if the day and month are the same but not necessarily the years are the same)

Example:

```
>>>strvar1 = 'abc-123'
>>>strvar2 = 'abc-456'
>>>strvar1.myfunction(strvar2)
True
```

Class code

```
class Date(object):
     def __init__(self, x0 = 1900, y0 = 1, z0 = 1):
        self.x = x0
        self.y = y0
        self.z = z0
     def __str__(self):
        date = str(self.x) + "-" + str(self.y).rjust(2, '0') + "-" + str(self.z).rjust(2, '0')
        return date  
     def myFunction(j):
```

So with the example it would look like:

```
d1 = Date(1999, 1, 1) //d1 = "1999-01-01"
d2 = Date(2000, 2, 2) //d2 = "2000-02-02"
d3 = Date(2001, 2, 2) //d3 = "2001-02-02"

>>>d1.myFunction(d2)
False
>>>d2.myFuction(d3)
True
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What language? Can you show relevant code in your class?

Comment: Sorry, this is the first question I've asked. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes absolutely, this is a reason for having classes. Read up on https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html.

```
 def myFunction(self, cdate):
     return self.y == cdate.y and self.z == cdate.z
```

Comment: That was absolutely what I needed. That link you provided was also very helpful. Thank you so much. I had been roadblocked by this for so long.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to perform a comparison before method invocation you could use the ternary operator to evaluate a condition then return the variable you want. An example is listed below written in JavaScript

```
var a = 1
var b = 2
myObj.myMethod( (a>b) ? a : b );
```

In the above example the ternary syntax

```
(a>b) ? a : b
```

will evaluate a is greater than b then return a if true otherwise if a is less than b it will return b.

[Ternary Wiki Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Without knowing language you may want to check out the wiki page for your languages particular syntactical implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with a class-based approach, but functional programming has a solution for this too, in partial functions:

```
def make_has_same_month_day(d1):
    """return a function that takes a date
    and returns true if the month and day are the same as the enclosed date"""
    def has_same_month_day(d2):
        return d1.y == d2.y and d1.z == d2.z
    return has_same_month_day
```

This can also be written using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

```
from functools import partial
def same_month_day(d1, d2):
    """return true if both dates have the same month and day"""
    return d1.y == d2.y and d1.z == d2.z
has_same_month_day = partial(same_month_day, d1)
```